# PHP - Best practice to store project related settings in a config file

Tags: php

I am working on a mid sized PHP web application project. I've kept all projectwise settings in a .php file(config.php) as below.

**config.php**

```
return array(
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pwd',
    'dbname'   => 'db1',
);
```

(It has other settings also apart from database).

I can include it in any php file, using **include_once** wherever required.
Instead of this, if I write a singleton class to read the config file, will it be more efficient? Will it save some time because the file need not be included every time? I want to know which approach will be better and why? Thanks.

Comment: i will say to use constants as possible and also if possible then follow Laravel (.env) or Yii config file.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the dotenv way

[github](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)

This way you can store all the settings relevant to your enviroment in there and other people working on the project can have their own .env file.

as for execution time saved with **include_once** vs a singleton it's going to be negligible.

Comment: github link is broken.